# Insert If duplicate not found in table else update

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I wanted to ignore or update duplicate when I am going to insert values. I know about `on duplicate key` but i can't figure out the solution with that. Here is sample table example.

```
| ID   | roll     | sub   | mark |
| ---- |----------| ------|------|
|   1  | 100      | 11    |  15  |
|   2  | 101      | 11    |  16  |
|   3  | 102      | 11    |  17  |
|   4  | 100      | 12    |  10  |
|   5  | 101      | 12    |  11  |
|   6  | 102      | 12    |  12  |
```

Here the `id` is `primary key` but I wanted to insert to check if `roll & sub` already exist then update otherwise insert new row. I've tried with the following code but that's insert duplicate row but it should update row 6 in following table.

```
CREATE INDEX mycompo_index on student(roll,sub);

insert into student(roll, mark, sub)
            values (102, 22, 12)
on duplicate key update mark = values(mark);
```

Comment: If you don't want duplicates, you should define the combination of roll and sub as an additional key.

Comment: What's the type of key can make column combination and how to make it can you explain me please

Comment: Since this indeed seems to be the issue, I added an answer explaining it (it's more convenient than comments) - see there.

Comment: Okey Thanks for your answer and that's work good. But i have a question on that I make a `unique` key to combine two cols but i have another primary key 'id' do the id field meking any problem or else

Comment: No, that's not a problem. Although you can have only one primary key, you can have as many unique fields/combinations as you want. Each one will be evaluated for uniqueness independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the combination of `roll` and `sub` should be unique, you should define such a key in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE student ADD CONSTRAINT student_uq UNIQUE(roll, sub)
```

Note that if you do this, you don't have to explicitly create the index you're creating, the constraint will create on for you. Once you have this is place, you can use the `on duplicate key` syntax you were trying to use:

```
INSERT INTO student(roll, mark, sub)
VALUES (102, 22, 12)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mark = VALUES(mark)
```